# How do backend applications authenticate webseal headers?

Tags: webseal

I am new to IBM ISAM and webseal.

How do backend web applications verify that the IV headers (e.g. iv-user) is created by webseal and not some malicious third party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't :)

Generally a sort of IP filter or similar is the best to use here, so the application can ensure that the request originates from a known webseal server.

An alternative to iv-* headers is to create some sort of signed token such as a JWT token that can be verified by the application.

Comment: seems like there's no validation. i decided to do mutual ssl.

Comment: i am also new at IBM Webseal is there any turotial how to implement & configure IBM Webseal with spring boot ??